Could we replace 'of' with 'in' or 'among' in 'Construction [ii], with the content clause itself as subject, is much the least frequent of the three'?

Construction [ii], with the content clause itself as subject, is much
the least frequent of the three; use of the fact facilitates the
incorporation of the content clause into the subject when there is a
preference for positioning it early in the matrix clause, rather than
later, as in the extraposition construction.

Could we replace 'of' with 'in' or 'among'? Is this, of the three, a fixed usage?

The least/most [adjective] of the three (or any number) is a fixed usage.

Mary is the youngest of the three daughters of Mr and Mrs Smith.

In doesn't sound right. Among could be used with a larger number.

Mary is the fastest runner among all the girls in her class.

